My code doesn't accept op coin it always gives me ether coin
I have this code for mevbot

def build_transaction(to_address, value_in_op, gas_price):
    gas_limit = 21000  # قد تحتاج إلى تعديل هذا بناءً على نوع المعاملة
    value_in_wei = web3.to_wei(value_in_op, 'ether')
    gas_cost = gas_limit * gas_price
    total_cost = gas_cost + value_in_wei

    # تحقق من أن الرصيد يكفي لتغطية التكلفة
    balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(account.address).call()
    if total_cost > balance:
        print("Insufficient balance to cover the transaction cost.")
        return None

    return {
        'to': to_address,
        'value': value_in_wei,
        'gas': gas_limit,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
        'chainId': 10  # شبكة Optimism الرئيسية
    }



On optimism you still use ETH as gas, not OP token.

The problem appear to be in the build_transaction checks the account's OP token balance instead of the ether balance.
Note: I won't recommend to run a script that you don't understand what it is doing.

There is no MEV or mempool on Optimism, so it is likely some sort of scam.
